# Does picking your nose make it grow?

Tags: physiology

Does pulling/tugging at your soft cartilage cause it to grow?

Example of claim on [answers.com](http://wiki.answers.com/Q/How_do_you_make_your_nose_smaller_without_using_plastic_surgery)

> Don't pick your nose. Compulsive nose picking, known as rhinotillexomania, can increase the size of your nose and introduce infections or more serious problems.

Comment: Do you have sources that say it does?

Comment: @Chad I can confirm that it’s a common tale told to little children to prevent them from picking their nose in Germany.

Comment: I thought no one would have done a [scientific study on nose-picking](http://www.citeulike.org/user/AJCann/article/5106847), but it's been done and the authors won the 2001 IgNobel for a study that “cannot or should not be reproduced”

Comment: You can pick your nose, and you can pick your friends, but you can't pick your friends nose...~[hypatia](http://www.physicsforums.com/showthread.php?t=455209)

Comment: @Konrad: I never heard it before, and I live as well in Germany. I would expect, if you tell this to little boys, they will not pick their nose, but ... :)

Comment: @bobobobo: You can grow your `nose` by constantly picking, but it will not stay that big. :)

Comment: I am very interested in the answer for this. I confirm that in colombia it is a common tale aswell.

Comment: Don't our noses keep on growing anyway?